# Plink and X display location

Tags: window, x11, plink, xming

Using X forwarding with Putty there is an option to specify the X display location, e.g. localhost:100.  How can I do the same think using Plink?  I wish to have multiple X servers on the same box with different display locations, and need to be able to direct X forwarding to a specific one.

Answer (score 1):

You could create multiple PuTTY sessions and configure the X forwarding as desired. Then you can use plink and load a stored session:

```
plink.exe -load my_session_1 -l my_user_name -pw my_password <here comes your command>

plink.exe -load my_session_2 -l my_user_name -pw my_password <here comes your command>
```